# Run Python module with absolute path

Tags: python, bash, python-module

For this  file layout:

```
devel/
    pkg/
        __init__.py
        moduleA.py
        moduleB.py
        test/
            __init__.py
            test_A.py
            test_B.py
```

If I am in the directory which contains the pkg (devel), I can run:

```
python -m pkg.test.test_A
```

**But what if I want to run the same but with absobule path?** 
I tried:

```
python -m /Users/me/docs/devel/pkg.test.test_A
```

Assuming I don't want to do the following and change the directory in my bash script:

```
cd /Users/me/docs/devel/
python -m pkg.test.test_A
```

Is there any direct way from `python` command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `/Users/me/docs/devel` to your module search path:

```
PYTHONPATH=/Users/me/docs/devel python -m pkg.test.test_A
```

Comment: So that's the only way? Because you know, you can run any sole file with the absolute path `python /path/to/file/file.py`. Thanks

Comment: Either way should work, although note that you can't mix file paths and dotted module names; you would need `python /Users/me/docs/devel/pkg/test/testA.py`.

Comment: Yes I tried that unsuccessfully on my first attempt. I have relative imports (`from .. import`) inside the testA so I can only run it as a module. Pythonpath should be fine. Thank you